# What is the best regular expression generator/explainer

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to programming and I'm using C# 2010. There are some quite long (50 lines) regular expressions in code I need to maintain. Also I need to parse some text files with a lot of information. Can you recommend a tool for these tasks?

Comment: Did you write the 50-line regex? Because if it's not documented it will be almost impossible to understand and maintain. I would be worried about maintaining something that large

Comment: No, I didn't and there is no documentation, beside a comment with an example of a match. Actually it's my first job and I only started this Monday.

Comment: @Lincoln good luck at your first job :)

Comment: I see why the previous guy quit, he most probably didn't understand this regex too! ;-)

Comment: I wonder if there are any tools from translating from one regular expression syntax to another (e. g., generating a C# regular expression from a JavaScript regular expression).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two tools :

regexbuddy -> http://www.regexbuddy.com/

and expresso -> http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

First is not free while second is. Both provide similar characteristics. I personally use the first one no idea why :D

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Less than $50 isn't really much of a difference.

Answer (score 12):

Click the "Explain" checkbox before hitting Submit at http://myregextester.com and you'll get the great output from [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAPE-Regex-Explain/)

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:[foo]bar(baz))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [foo]                    any character of: 'f', 'o', 'o'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  bar                      'bar'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    baz                      'baz'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Very cool "Explain" tool! It even does indentation in addition to the commentification. +1

Answer (score 4):

@Lincoln
I sympathize with your problem. Unfortunately regexes have very little scope for internal documentation so a 50-line one is essentially like a binary program. Be aware that if you change 1 character in it the whole things will break. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) for example is a regex for a date:

> `^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`
>
> Analyze this regular expression with RegexBuddy matches a date in
>   `yyyy-mm-dd` format from between `1900-01-01` and `2099-12-31`, with a
>   choice of four separators. The anchors make sure the entire variable
>   is a date, and not a piece of text containing a date. The year is
>   matched by `(19|20)\d\d`. I used alternation to allow the first two
>   digits to be `19` or `20`.

If you didn't know it was a date then it would require a detective-like or cryptanalytic approach to work out what it was doing. Regex buddy and so will help a bit, but not give the semantics.

My guess is that your 50-line regex (I shudder when I write those words) will have dates and company ids and addresses and goodness knows what embedded in it.

The only goodish news is that regexes are less dependent on the language than they used to be. So if it was originally written in Java it probably works in C# and vice versa.

Is it simply used for identifying fields or are there capture groups? These are balanced brackets which extract subfields into a program through an API. By examining what these fields contain you may have a useful pointer to what the regex does.

Pragmatically, unless it's on the critical path, try to touch it as little as possible!

Answer (score 4):

Another online tool : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2):

Just found a really cool regular expression *explainer* tool:

```
http://www.regexper.com/
```

"*Behind the scenes, RegExper is a Ruby application which translates regular expressions into an SVG image. The SVG is embedded in the page, but it should be possible to extract or copy it for use in your own documentation.*"

For more infos read this blog post:

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/regexper-regular-expressions-explained/
```