# regular expression translator

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression generator/explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883415/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-generator-explainer)

Is there a way to go from a regular expression to what does it mean? 
for example I found the following expression in an old code:

```
.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*
```

...but I do not know if this is 100% correct or if it contains any unnecessary characters?
Is there any online tool that does regular expression translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. You can enter both the Regex and the text you want to apply it to. It also contains a couple of samples.

Comment: i do not understand why in the above expression he started with .* and ended with .*

Comment: as long as .* match anything it will only match one time per line. I guess...