# how to make a regular expression pattern?

Tags: c#

i have a html file like below:(i'm new in regular expression pattern)

```
<a href=":$451$142">some thing</a>
<a href=":$14$15">some thing</a>                                
<a href=":$3$16">some thing</a>                     
<a href=":$312$17">some thing</a>
```

how can i replace all the ":$Number$Number" with "#"?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex, I thought there was a very clear post about this on SO on why it CANNOT be done, and should NOT be done!

Comment: How about using jQuery instead? `$('a').prop('href','#');`

Comment: i'm try this address:http://www.rubular.com/r/1zWQQVLZy1,but i could not make one

Comment: this is a html file and i want to convert it to my need format

Comment: The answer to your question is on Stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883415/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-generator-explainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
       String str = @"<a href="":$451$142"">some thing</a>  "+
                    @" <a href="":$14$15"">some thing</a>   "+                             
                    @" <a href="":$3$16"">some thing</a>    "+                 
                    @" <a href="":$312$17"">some thing</a>  ";
       String newStr = Regex.Replace(str,@":\$\d+\$\d+", "#");
       System.Console.WriteLine(str);
       System.Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + newStr);
```

It yields:

```
<a href=":$451$142">some thing</a>   <a href=":$14$15">some thing</a>    <a href
=":$3$16">some thing</a>     <a href=":$312$17">some thing</a>


<a href="#">some thing</a>   <a href="#">some thing</a>    <a href="#">some thin
g</a>     <a href="#">some thing</a>
```

The regular expression: `:\$\d+\$\d+` will match any piece of text starting with a `:`, followed by a `$` (the `$` is a special character in regular expression language and thus needs to be escaped with an extra `\` in front). The `$` will in turn need to be followed by one or more digits (`\d+`) which in turn is followed by another `:` which is followed by one or more numbers (`\d+`). Please check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) tutorial for more information.

Although in this case regular expressions did help, it is highly recommended that you do not use them to parse languages. Please use a dedicated framework such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to do any HTML related processes. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517804/htmlagilitypack-example-for-changing-links-doesnt-work-how-do-i-accomplish-thi) for an example similar to what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: @irsog: No worries. However, if I where you, I would opt for the HTML Agility pack solution. HTML **should never** be processed by regular expressions.